# how can I remove tag only

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I need remove some tag only in xml file.

xml:

```
<p>Originally published <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="ref155">Klein, F. (1978)</xref> <i>Priam Books. Reproduced by permission of the author.</p>
```

script:

```
use XML::Twig;
my $xml_twig_content = XML::Twig->new(
keep_encoding => 1,
twig_handlers => {
keep_atts_order => 1,
'xref' => \&xref,
},
pretty_print => 'indented',
);
$xml_twig_content->parsefile('sample.xml');

sub xref {
 my ($xml_twig_content, $xref) = @_;
 my $XrefName = $xref->att('ref-type');
 if ($XrefName =~ /^bibr$/si){
 $xref->delete;
 }
}
```

I got output:

```
<p>Originally published <i>Priam Books. Reproduced by permission of the author.</p>
```

I need output:

```
<p>Originally published Klein, F. (1978) <i>Priam Books. Reproduced by permission of the author.</p>
```

How can I remove xref tag and retain its content?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`erase`-method](http://www.xmltwig.org/xmltwig/twig_dev.html#METHODS_XML_Twig_Elt_erase):

> `erase`
>
> Erase the element: the element is deleted and all of its children are pasted in its place.

Here's your `sub` using it:

```
sub xref {
  my ( $twig, $xref ) = @_;
  $xref->erase;
}
```

---

Note that for me, your example XML did not parse because the `<i>` was not closed.

Answer (score 2):

Why is the `keep_encoding => 1` bit inside the `twig_handlers` bit? Is there something in the docs that's wrong?

I would do this in a simpler way, using `twig_roots`/`twig_print_outside_roots` to pass through everything but the `xref`s you are interested in:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new( keep_encoding => 1,
                twig_roots => { 'xref[@ref-type=~/^(?i:bibr)/]' => sub { print $_->inner_xml; } },
                twig_print_outside_roots => 1,
              )
         ->parsefile('sample.xml');
```

the `twig_roots` option is triggered only for the proper `xref`s. The `@ref-type=~/^(?i:bibr)/]` bit uses an XML::Twig extension to XPath that lets you use regexps like in Perl, the `(?i:` part makes it non case-sensitive. For those elements, print the inner XML, not the tag.

the `twig_print_outside_roots`option (I know it's a looong option name!) causes everything but the xref elements to be output as-is, so you don't have to worry about keeping the attribute order or the indentation, it will be the same as in the original XML.